# Image Not Aligning to Center in Bootstrap Row

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I used Bootstrap grid to centre the position of the 4 images in Angular. The images align perfectly to the centre in the `row` when I placed them within the same `HTML` sheet. However, if I placed them in a different `HTML` sheet, the 4 images are not exactly positioned in the centre, as I notice they are slightly off to the left.

To summarise, **this works** (./home.component.html):

```
<div class="container">

    <p class="h2-responsive itemsTitle">Items with free shipping</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <img class="itemCard" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505429155379-441cc7a574f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0ddea5332a8ab2d09cf5eec6a57d3f9f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <img class="itemCard" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505429155379-441cc7a574f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0ddea5332a8ab2d09cf5eec6a57d3f9f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <img class="itemCard" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505429155379-441cc7a574f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0ddea5332a8ab2d09cf5eec6a57d3f9f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <img class="itemCard" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505429155379-441cc7a574f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0ddea5332a8ab2d09cf5eec6a57d3f9f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**But this doesn't** (./home.component.html):

```
<div class="container">

    <p class="h2-responsive itemsTitle">Items with free shipping</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <app-home-item></app-home-item>
        <app-home-item></app-home-item>
        <app-home-item></app-home-item>
        <app-home-item></app-home-item>
    </div>

</div>
```

(./home-item.component.html):

```
<div class="col-sm">
    <img class="itemCard" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505429155379-441cc7a574f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0ddea5332a8ab2d09cf5eec6a57d3f9f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
</div>
```

Here's what happens. The circled part shows that the images are slightly off to the left, which doesn't happen when I use the first example code above.

[image]

I am not too sure where it goes wrong. All the components are imported and declared in app.module. The bootstrap link is placed in the `index.html` as well.

*CSS (in styles.css):*

```
.itemsTitle {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.itemCard {
  width: 15rem;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap version?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.0.0

Comment: You want the 4 images in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the width of col inside `app-home-item` so in that component add `flex: 1;` to the wrapper

Comment: I am just wondering how come the same piece of code works when placed together inside `home.component.html`, but doesn't work when separated?

Comment: I don't think it does, I think it just is less noticeable. Images and cols now are properly align? Now it should be 4 cols in each row and using all the avaliable space.

Comment: No, the images become very small.

Comment: What's the width of the parent (div) of those images? Check for tags not closing.

Comment: You mean `<div class="col-sm">`? It is 270px. The width of the entire row is 1140px.

Comment: Add `width: 100%;` to the img maybe, hard to debug without an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168965/discussion-between-steven-and-fecosos).